# symfony First call take too much time

Tags: php, symfony, caching

why Symfony takes too much time on first call, then OK, then after some mins too much time again.

- Permanent MYSQL connection (improve speed, but not the solution)
- Symfony file cache not generated/modified after a long request, so it seems not to be the source of the problem.
- Logs / Debug etc, seems not be be the source of the problem.

Any help please

Comment: look ar SF2 debugger & chrome/ firefox console to identify probleme. Ithink anyone can't help without more information sorry. Did you work on server ?

Comment: I work with web services Rest type
I even tried to make a function that is just an echo for the first time he spends 10 seconds, the second time one second
my question is there something by default in symfony that does this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if need ;)
I found two solutions

1/
`php composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize`
and configure opcache in the server ;)

2/
in the config.yml file in the framework section, add these

```
 `framework`:
    # configuration du profiler
    profiler:
        enabled:              false
        collect:              true
        only_exceptions:      false
        only_master_requests: false
        dsn:                  file:%kernel.cache_dir%/profiler
        username:
        password:
        lifetime:2592000
```

Comment: I noticed the slow response on windows however symfony loads and works pretty fast since I have moved to Ubuntu

Comment: I use a mac, I tried even in a ubuntu environment.
what has worked for me is what I mentioned just above